# Estimating elasticity using different regression models

Tags: regression, probit, elasticity

My question is how to estimate elasticity based on a Probit model. I know the following formulas are used to estimate elasticity based on OLS (1) and logit (2) models (Ewing & Cervero, 2001):

(1) ϵ=β(X/Y)
(2) ϵ=β*X*(1-P)

where ϵ is the elasticity, β is the coefficient of the independent variable of interest, X is the sample mean of the independent variable, Y is the sample mean of the dependent variable, and P is the mean estimated probability of occurrence. Given this, how should I estimate elasticity when I have a probit regression?

Reference:
Ewing, R., & Cervero, R. (2001). Travel and the built environment: a synthesis. Transportation Research Record: Journal of the Transportation Research Board, (1780), 87-114.

Comment: Is X continuous?

Comment: My models have the basic form "F(X)=β0+β1X1+β2X2+...+β3X3" some X values are continuous (e.g., income) and some are binary (e.g., democrat vs republican). F(X) refers to the adoption of environmental policies.

Answer (score 3):

You know that the conditional mean of the dependent variable in a probit model is
$$E[y=1 \vert x,z]=\Phi(\alpha + \beta \cdot x +z \cdot \pi).$$
This is also you predicted probability, $\Pr(y=1 \vert x,z)$. Here $\Phi(.)$ is the standard normal cdf, and $\varphi(.)$ is is the standard normal pdf, which will be used below.

The standard elasticity formula is

$$ \epsilon = \frac{\partial E[y \vert x,z]}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{x}{E[y \vert x, z]}$$

The marginal effect for a *continuous* variable $x$ in a probit model is
$$\frac{\partial E[y=1 \vert x,z]}{\partial x}=\varphi(\alpha + \beta \cdot x +z \cdot \pi)\cdot \beta .$$

This comes from applying the chain rule for derivatives to the expectation and the fact that $\varphi()$ is the derivative of $\Phi()$. You can plug that in for the first term in the elasticity formula. The denominator in the second term is just the predicted probability.

For a discrete $z$, a semi-elasticity makes more sense (percent change in probability when $z$ goes from 0 to 1). You can approximate a small percentage change in the probability by taking differences of logged predictions with $z$ set to one less the prediction with $z$ set to zero:

$$\ln \Phi(\alpha + \beta \cdot x +1 \cdot \pi) - \ln \Phi(\alpha + \beta \cdot x +0 \cdot \pi).$$

Some people multiply this by 100 to convert to percent.

For both the elasticity and the semi-elasticity, you can average these in some sample or calculate them at representative/interesting values of the covariates. You can also plot curves or surfaces of these functions.